# Python - how to correctly use htmlparser on alexa.com

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

So, I've tried to get the first 20 websites from **www.alexa.com/topsites/global** in my application, but I don't get the desired result.

My code so far using `HTMLParser` and `urllib2`:

```
import HTMLParser, urllib2

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def reset(self):
        HTMLParser.HTMLParser.reset(self)
        self.in_a = False
        self.next_link_text_pair = None
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag=='a':
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name=='href':
                    self.next_link_text_pair = [value, '']
                    self.in_a = True
                    break
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_a: self.next_link_text_pair[1] += data
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag=='a':
            if self.next_link_text_pair is not None:
                print self.next_link_text_pair
            self.next_link_text_pair = None
            self.in_a = False

if __name__=='__main__':
    p = MyHTMLParser()
    p.feed(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.alexa.com/topsites/global').read())
```

The result that I get:

```
['/', '']
['/topsites', 'Browse Top Sites']
['/', 'Home']
['/plans', 'Plans and Pricing']
['/tools', 'Tools']
['/pro/dashboard', 'My Dashboard']
['/toolbar', 'Toolbar']
['/about', 'About Us']
['/support', 'Support']
['http://blog.alexa.com', 'Blog']
['/secure/login?resource=%2Ftopsites%2Fglobal', 'Sign In']
['/register?resource=%2Ftopsites%2Fglobal', 'Create an Account']
['/topsites/countries', 'By Country']
['/topsites/category', 'By Category']
['/siteinfo/google.com', 'Google.com']
['/siteinfo/facebook.com', 'Facebook.com']
['/siteinfo/youtube.com', 'Youtube.com']
['/siteinfo/baidu.com', 'Baidu.com']
['/siteinfo/yahoo.com', 'Yahoo.com']
['/siteinfo/wikipedia.org', 'Wikipedia.org']
['/siteinfo/amazon.com', 'Amazon.com']
['/siteinfo/twitter.com', 'Twitter.com']
['/siteinfo/taobao.com', 'Taobao.com']
['/siteinfo/qq.com', 'Qq.com']
['/siteinfo/google.co.in', 'Google.co.in']
['/siteinfo/linkedin.com', 'Linkedin.com']
```

I would like to get rid of the first undesired results such as `Home` and `Plan and pricing` and so on and only get the first 20 website **names** without the `['/siteinfo/` thing.

Can anybody help me out ? *I don't want to use BeautifulSoup*.

Comment: why don't you want to use BeautifulSoup? This take about three lines using requests and bs4

Comment: Because I am doing this app remote and I don't have superuser access to `pip` it. So I have to handle this without it

Comment: You don't need superuser permissions to install pip or BeautifulSoup, I got all the results you require in two lines using requests and BeautifulSoup

Comment: I already have pip, but I am getting some error when I am trying to `pip install beautifulSoup4` which says that I don't have access to download it, so this is unfortunately not an option for me

Comment: so you have no write permissions anywhere? Also all the links you want are in the `desc-paragraph` tag, http://pastebin.com/n6PEkE5b

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. But how can I use this information in order to get what I need ? And more, exactly 20 websites.

Comment: All you need to do is slice, `[p.a["href"] for p in desc][:20]` or more efficiently use a generator expression

Comment: I get an error after putting that before this line: `if tag=='a':` . The error says that `global name desc is not defined`

Comment: that was an example using my own code, you need to store the tags you want in a list breaking the loop when you reach 20 or slice the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the URL starts with `/siteinfo/` to eliminate irrelevant ones:

```
if self.next_link_text_pair is not None:
    if self.next_link_text_pair[0].startswith('/siteinfo/'):
        print self.next_link_text_pair[1]
```

Comment: What about the unnecessary urls from the begining ? How can I parse only the first 20 websites ?

Comment: It worked, but now every website is parsed twice. Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally write two `print`s?

Comment: I am positive. @Selcuk

Comment: @Alexander It works fine for me. I get 25 results total.

Comment: It was a simple typo in my code. It worked. Thank you. How about printing just the first 20 ? I've tried @Padraic solution but it's not working.

Comment: Do you want to just print them or use for something later? You can append them to a list then print the first 20 at the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74056/discussion-between-alexander-and-selcuk).